# Função síncrona para verificar arquivos no NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, express.js

Estou criando PDF's no meu servidor NodeJS usando o framework Express e a biblioteca PdfMake. Se alguém olhar meu perfil vai ver que fiz uma pergunta sobre PDF corrompido após o download. Acontece que eu descobri que os arquivos estão corrompidos porquê eles são enviados para download antes mesmo de ser concluído a criação deles, pois todo o processo ocorre de forma assíncrona. 
O que eu preciso saber é o seguinte: Com qual processo SÍNCRONO eu poderia verificar se o arquivo está pronto e pode ser enviado para download, ou como faço para criar o PDF de forma síncrona??

Servidor:

```
pdfMake = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
pdfMake.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('../pdfs/Tabela.pdf'));
console.log('Imprimiu!!');
pdfMake.end();
if(fs.existsSync('C:/ProjetosLeonardo/Relatorios/pdfs/Tabela.pdf')) {
    let file = 'C:/ProjetosLeonardo/Relatorios/pdfs/Tabela.pdf';
    res.download(file);
}
```

Cliente:

```
 axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/server/gerarpdf',
      responseType: 'arraybuffer',
      data: this.pessoas
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      let blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'})
      let link = document.createElement('a')
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      link.download = 'TabelaTeste.pdf'
      link.click()
    })
```

Comment: Compartilhe o trecho de código relevante da criação e download do arquivo por favor.

Comment: Está adicionado, peço desculpas pelo incoveniente...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode ser enviado quando o evento terminar:

```
pdfMake = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
let stream = pdfMake.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('../pdfs/Tabela.pdf'));
pdfMake.end();

stream.on('finish', function() {
    if(fs.existsSync('C:/ProjetosLeonardo/Relatorios/pdfs/Tabela.pdf')) {
        let file = 'C:/ProjetosLeonardo/Relatorios/pdfs/Tabela.pdf';
        res.download(file);
    }
}
```

Você consegue "ouvir" certos eventos porque Streams são `EventEmitter`, por isso você conseguirá detectar quando estiver terminado.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, conforme eu esperava. Muito obrigado!